# Error when I try to include Bootstrap and Fontawesome to a Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, bootstrap-4

I try to install Bootstrap and Fontawesome to my Laravel (latest version) Project.

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
npm install
npm run watch
```

I encountered this error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    Error: Cannot find module './src/data'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
```

webpack.mix.js is the default file in Laravel release, I never changed it:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

This is my resources/js/app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

My bootstrap.js:

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

What am I missing?
What can I try?

Comment: Please put code from webpack js.

Comment: I added webpack.mix.js

Comment: I just tried your steps for fresh installed laravel, there is no problem, do you also want to add your `resources/js/app.js` and `bootstrap.js`?

Comment: this is so weird, I cannot reproduce this bug, everything is fine when I compile all the assets.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to install Laravel from stretch again this evening. My npm version is 6.4.1. May be I should update this.